# R insert a comma after a value

Tags: r

On a UNIX system, I can easily do a global change in a file. Eg, let's say I have a year value of /2021 and it will be unique in the file and associated with the date, so I can do a global change and insert a comma after the /2021. This then lets me read the file into R using comma delimiters. Is there any way I can read a string eg

`7/06/2021 23:45` and change that to `7/06/2021, 23:45` in R running on Windows?

Thanks.

The data is as follows with previous columns removed and linefeeds inserted to show the data as a list.

```
ReadingDate Units Read.Type

08/06/2021 0:00     0    Actual

07/06/2021 23:45     0    Actual

07/06/2021 23:30     0    Actual

07/06/2021 23:15     0    Actual

07/06/2021 23:00     0    Actual

07/06/2021 22:45     0    Actual
```

`ReadingDate` is the date and time, so there are three columns. I would like four with time separated from date via a comma.

Answer (score 2):

If your input would always be a date and time component, separated by a single space, then just use `sub` here in fixed mode:

```r
date <- "7/06/2021 23:45"
output <- sub(" ", ", ", date, fixed=TRUE)
output

[1] "7/06/2021, 23:45"
```

To apply the above logic to a data frame column, use:

```r
df$ReadingDate <- sub(" ", ", ", df$ReadingDate, fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That never occurred to me. I was looking at changing the date format but this seems so much easier. I just need to figure out how to do that to each value in the column.

Comment: Just replace `date` with `your_df$date`, and assign to whatever column you want on the LHS.

Comment: I am struggling to do as you suggested in replacing the date with my df$date. Every method seems to be short one row or a bunch of unwanted stuff is chucked in. Do you have any suggestion? I can do a loop to get the date, run that example you provided but then it seems to get messy.

Comment: I can only answer what I can see.  Edit your question if my answer still leaves you with some doubts.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I want to either replace 08/06/2021 0:00 or just insert a new data frame column with the value 08/06/2021, 0:00 for each row. The sub works well but something I am doing is not counting the rows properly.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Perhaps this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise it was that simple. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: There is no green checkmark, only the flags for attention. If it is a rating, I have already done that earlier.